Automation Android apps with script
I would like to create a script that automates the operation of an application used to control a lawn mower. I would like the application to connect to my http server to receive information, and then, depending on the data received, turn on mowing via the application on the phone.
App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.husqvarna.automowerconnect)
Android version: 11
I need some list of steps or solutions on how to do it so I can choose the right one for me.
At first I thought about tools that automate clicks, but they are very limited and won't execute http requests. Later I came up with the idea of ​​using bash or python scripts in termux, but I don't know the libraries and solutions available.
How can i do that?

Here’s how you can automate your lawn mower app using Zennodroid:

Connect to your server: Use Zennodroid to send an HTTP request to your server to get the data (like when to start mowing).
Decide what to do: Based on what the server sends back (e.g., a command to start mowing), you'll automate the app to turn on the mower.
Control the Mower app: Use Zennodroid to interact with the app, like tapping buttons or adjusting settings, depending on the command.
Repeat if you need it: Set up the script to regularly check in with your server, so it can keep the lawn mower running as needed.

This will let you remotely control your mower via the app based on info from your server, all automated through Zennodroid. The service offers a 14-day free trial version https://zennolab.com/en/products/zennodroid/.
